# How to use XSL:For-Each within child tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to build an XSLT such in the output XML each permission from input should be present within one tag separated by ,

All the 3 files, input XML, XSLT and output XML are below please suggest what chnages should I do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Input>
    <UserAccount _id="Name">
        <permissions>
            <PermissionName name="pem1 "/>
            <PermissionName name="pem 2"/>
            <PermissionName name="pem 3"/>
        </permissions>
        <preferredLanguage code="en" display="English"/>
    </UserAccount>
</Input>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Output>
            <xsl:for-each select="Input/UserAccount">
            <out>
                <xsl:element name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@_id"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="Language">
                    <xsl:value-of select="preferredLanguage/@code"/>
                </xsl:element>
                </out>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Output>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what I am expecting in output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Output>
    <out>
        <name>Name</name>
        <Language>en</Language>
        <Permission>pem1, pem 2, pem 3</Permission>
    </out>
</Output>
```

Comment: Your question is tagged as `xslt-2.0` bur your stylesheet says `version="1.0"`. Why is that? Does your processor indeed support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: This is for XSLT 2.0. i want the answer in 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you could do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Output>
            <xsl:for-each select="Input/UserAccount">
              <out>
                <name>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@_id"/>
                </name>
                <Language>
                  <xsl:value-of select="preferredLanguage/@code"/>
                </Language>
                <Permission>
                  <xsl:value-of select="permissions/PermissionName/@name" separator=", "/>
                </Permission>
              </out>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Output>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pP7K7g7